# What's the missing white card in this New Phyrexia cycle?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

There's a cycle of instants and sorceries in New Phyrexia that have an effect and adds at the end a loss of life to the targeted player or the targeted permanent's controller: [Vapor Snag](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Vapor%20Snag), [Geth's Verdict](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=214376), [Victorious Destruction](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Victorious%20Destruction) and [Glissa's Scorn](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=194171).

Or, at least I think it's a cycle. Problem is, I can't find the white one! Is there one, and I'm missing it? Was this lack of symmetry intentional by WotC?

Answer (score 3):

**These aren't a cycle per se.**

Note the fifth one, [Psychic Barrier](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPsychic%20Barrier%5d):

[image: Psychic Barrier]

It's more that "loses 1 life" (or "[gets a poison counter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=213744)") was seen as an easy thing to tack onto staple effects to make them feel more "Phyrexian".

Comment: D'oh, totally forgot about this guy!

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, "controller loses 1 life" isn't really a white thing to do.

If I were to choose a common instant/sorcery in white to fit into the cycle, I would choose [War Report](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=230078).

Instead of "hating" something and then having the controller lose life, White "loves" something (creatures and artifacts) and has the caster gain life. Yeah, not a perfect fit, but rather the counterpoint of the other 4 colour cycle.

Comment: Well, blue, red and green don't usually get "opponent loses X life" either! All of the colours got a black-ish feel in New Phyrexia, even white as shown by [Suture Priest](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=217981).

Comment: See, I actually think of white as the king of "hate". Balance! Swords to Plowshares! Path to Exile! Disenchant! Wrath of God! Rule of Law! Ghostly Prison! Gaddock Teeg! Aven Mindcensor! Suture Priest! Elesh Norn! There is almost nothing that white doesn't punish in one way or another.